# How to use the same widget twice in pygtk?

Tags: python, widget, pygtk

This doesn't work well:

```
    image_log = gtk.Image()
    image_log.set_from_file("test.png")

    self.out_button = gtk.Button()
    self.out_button.add(image_log)

    self.err_button = gtk.Button()
    self.err_button.add(image_log)

    another_box.pack_start(self.out_button, False)
    another_box.pack_start(self.err_button, False)
```

The problem is, image_log is used twice and GTK doesn't like it. Is there some .copy() method? Or should I just use plain vanilla deepcopy?

**EDIT:** Looks like there is no default way to clone objects in GTK. Factory will do the trick in this case.

GTK warning:

```
app/gui.py:248: GtkWarning: gtk_box_pack: assertion `child->parent == NULL' failed
hbox_errlog.pack_start(image_log)
```

Comment: What is your GTK/PyGTK error output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a factory function to reduce code duplication

```
def make_image_from_file(fname):
  im = gtk.Image()
  im.set_from_file(fname)
  return im

self.out_button.set_image(make_image_from_file(..))
```

## Revisiting

There is a much more natural way. You will like it. In PyGTK 2.12+:

```
gtk.image_new_from_file(filename)
```

I had something in the back of my mind telling me this, but I didn't look it up.

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkimage.html#function-gtk--image-new-from-file

Comment: *shakes fist* :) ... Nice and concise.

Comment: Thanks kaizer.se! I knew there must be a straight forward way!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
def clone_widget(widget):
    widget2=widget.__class__()
    for prop in dir(widget):
        if prop.startswith("set_") and prop not in ["set_buffer"]:
            prop_value=None
                try:
                    prop_value=getattr(widget, prop.replace("set_","get_") )()
                except:
                    try:
                        prop_value=getattr(widget, prop.replace("set_","") )
                    except:
                        continue
                if prop_value == None:
                    continue
                try:
                    getattr(widget2, prop)( prop_value ) 
                except:
                    pass
return widget2
```

All this try ... except blocks are there because not all properties could be copied by using
set_prop(get_prop). I haven't tested this for all properties and widgets yet, but it worked well for gtkEntry. Maybe this is slow, but it's nice the use :)

Comment: Many thanks for this function - a slightly more updated version can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460848/templating-overflowing-content-with-glade-and-pygtk/20463925#20463925 ... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
image_log = gtk.Image()
image_log.set_from_file("test.png")
image_logb = gtk.Image()
image_logb.set_from_file("test.png")

self.out_button = gtk.Button()
self.out_button.add(image_log)

self.err_button = gtk.Button()
self.err_button.add(image_logb)

another_box.pack_start(self.out_button, False)
another_box.pack_start(self.err_button, False)
```

It is only an extra 2 lines of code, and maybe more efficient than cloning/copying the first image object.

That way you can treat `out_button` and `err_button` independently. But it should make sense to use the same `gtk.Image()` object for both buttons ... it is just an image.

**Edit** 
To avoid duplication (seems like *overkill* though) you could write a factory for gtk.Image() objects from the same image.

```
def gtkimage_factory(num_objs, image_file):
    i=0
    imglist = []
    while i<num_objs:
        img_ob = gtk.Image()
        img_ob.set_from_file(image_file)
        imglist.append( img_ob )
        i+=1
    return imglist
```

Or something along those lines, you get the idea. But a factory seems like overkill unless you are producing **loads** of these things and need them independently parented in GTK. 
Then...

```
image_list = gtkimg_factory(2, "test.png")

self.out_button = gtk.Button()
self.out_button.add(image_list[0])

self.err_button = gtk.Button()
self.err_button.add(image_list[1])

another_box.pack_start(self.out_button, False)
another_box.pack_start(self.err_button, False)
```

Maybe it is something to do with GTK resource management?

Comment: I am using this approach atm, but duplicating code is what I've always been avoiding. The problem sits because GTK sets parent to each widget (which can only be one).

Comment: Ah I see. Even though the code is duplication, they are required to be separate instances of gtk.Image() ... so it isn't really duplication. I added an edit.

Comment: gtk.Image is not just an image. It's a widget displaying an image.

Comment: @kaiser.se - Yup, that is what I meant. Didn't realize single parentage was enforced on all widgets.

Answer (score 0):

all if you want to use the collection of widgets arranged in some fashion, again and again, let's say a box with one entry box and a label(can be complex as hell if you want) and want to use it multiple time in your application like depending upon condition how many similar tabs are needed but obviously working with different data that use composites with glade.
With pygi(gi_composites) python library you can make your own widgets and use them multiple times.
[https://github.com/virtuald/pygi-composite-templates][1]